# How to let GCC linker (ld) generate a list of linked object library files, just like -M

Tags: makefile, ld

I have a project which generates a lot of exe files for unittest. Each time I modify a .c file, all unittests have to be re-compiled. It cost a lot of time.

Since most unittests do not depend on the modified .c file, it's unnecessary to do the recompilation. If the linker could generate a list of linked .o and .a files, then I can include it into the makefile to save some work, just just link the .d file generate by gcc -M.

Comment: If every `.h` requires only that the equivalent-named `.c` file's object be linked in, you can `sed` the depfiles. Beware that this requires doing the `-M` logic ahead of time, rather than lazily, which may have significant performance impact. Doing it solely based on directories is more efficient. Alternatively, try something like `test || gcc` although this might still be expensive and it will run every time. Possibly a 2-step rule with `touch $@.stamp` might help?

Comment: @o11c Thank you for your reply. The first method seems promising. The condition holds for most of my source files. I'ms sorry but what does test || gcc and touch $@.stamp mean? Could you please provide further explaination or reference links about them?

Comment: The rough idea is that, in a deeply nested rule, you detect that even though the timestamp has changed, the content hasn't. But you don't want to re-do all the checking every time, so you touch a timestamp to prevent it. I have not yet tested this idea and don't know how generally useful it is. Forcibly sorting everything by directory and/or hard-coding a few dependencies has always been enough. Although another possibility would be `strace`ing `ld` and/or making an `ld` wrapper script and dropping it in a directory specified by `-B` to implement `-M` by hand.